# How to set different text alignments for each text component in a wordpress plugin?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

In this example, each text component should have its own `text-align` style setting, but the `<AlignmentToolbar>` seems to only provide one alignment value. Is there way to get more than one alignment setting within the same plugin?

```
        <div {...blockProps}>
        <BlockControls>
            <AlignmentToolbar
                value={attributes.title_align}
                onChange={(val) => setAttributes({ title_align: val })}
            />
        </BlockControls>
        <article>
            <TextControl
                className="title"
                allowedFormats={['core/bold', 'core/italic']}
                style={{ textAlign: attributes.title_align }}
                onChange={(val) => setAttributes({ title: val })}
                value={attributes.title}
                placeholder={ __( 'Title...' ) }
            />
        </article>

        <article>
            <RichText
                tagName="div"
                className="message"
                allowedFormats={['core/bold', 'core/italic', 'core/link']}
                style={{ textAlign: attributes.title_align }}
                value={attributes.message}
                onChange={(val) => setAttributes({ message: val })}
                placeholder={ __( 'Message...' ) }
            />
        </article>
    </div>
```

Comment: Looks like you're saving the alignment value to the same variable, `title_align`?

Comment: Yes, but if I create 2 variables they will still both have the same alignment value as I don't see how to get more than one value from the alignment control.

Comment: I'm thinking now that this has to be done using custom settings in the right side bar panel as the block tool bar is intended to provide block level values and not component  specific values if there are multiple components in the plugin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way `<alignmentToolbar>` ([alignmentControl](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/HEAD/packages/block-editor/src/components/alignment-control/README.md)) works is by providing alignment options per block, so unfortunately you cannot have more than one per a block. A possible alternative way to accomplish this could be done with [InnerBlocks](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/block-tutorial/nested-blocks-inner-blocks/) which control each supported blocks alignment independently, eg:

```js
import { registerBlockType } from '@wordpress/blocks';
import { InnerBlocks, useBlockProps } from '@wordpress/block-editor';

registerBlockType('my-plugin/plugin-name', {
    edit: () => {
        const blockProps = useBlockProps();

        // Create a template of InnerBlocks with predefined attributes
        const MY_TEMPLATE = [
            ['core/heading', // Heading Block already implements RichText component
                {
                    placeholder: 'Title...',
                    level: 3,
                    className: 'title'
                }
            ],
            ['core/paragraph', // Paragraph allows multiple lines to be created
                {
                    placeholder: 'Message...',
                    className: 'message',
                }
            ]
        ];

        return (
            <div {...blockProps}>
                <InnerBlocks
                    template={MY_TEMPLATE}
                    templateLock="insert"
                />
            </div>
        );
    },

    save: () => {
        const blockProps = useBlockProps.save();

        return (
            <div {...blockProps}>
                <InnerBlocks.Content />
            </div>
        );
    },
});
```

By using the existing core blocks that [already implement the RichText component](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/richtext/#core-blocks-using-the-richtext-component), the style/alignment is done for you. To extend on this, if your block needs to be wrapped in `<article>`, you can create another custom block that contains just one `<RichText>` component to save your custom markup. Next, use the additional custom block within a InnerBlock template to enable custom text alignment per block.